# Error de cors vercel

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, cors, vercel

Subi mi `front` en `react` a `vercel` y mi `backend` en `nodeJS` tambien a `vercel`, cambie el codigo poniendo el url del dominio que me dio vercel pero me sale el error de `cors`:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sm-backend-ten.vercel.app/properties/getAll' from origin 'https://sm-inmobiliaria.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

No entiendo el porque, adjunto mi codigo donde hago la conección desde el `front`

```
import axios from "axios";

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://sm-back.vercel.app' });


export const getAllProperties = () => API.get('/properties/getAll');
export const getEstate = (id) => API.get(`/properties/getEstate/${id}`);
```

Y mi `index.js` de mi `backend`

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import AuthRoute from "./Routes/AuthRoute.js";
import UserRoute from "./Routes/UserRoute.js";
import StateRouter from "./Routes/StateRoute.js";
import RouterNew from "./Routes/RouterNew.js";
import cors from "cors";

//Routes
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`Listening at ${process.env.PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

// Usage of routes
app.use("/auth", AuthRoute);
app.use("/user", UserRoute);
app.use("/state", StateRouter);
app.use("/properties", RouterNew);
```

Añadí el origin en los `CORS` pero tampoco me funciono, alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo idea de como funciona vercel, pero el problema que pareces tener es que NO tienes montado ningun servidor de nodejs para tu backend...

Parece que solo pegaste los archivos de nodejs en un hosting para sitios estaticos. (entra a https://sm-backend-ten.vercel.app y veras que te retorna el archivo js).

valida si vercel tiene soporte para node js y sino busca un proveedor de hosting que si lo soporte.

nota: el cors no es algo que deba procuparte ahora porque lo esta lanzando vercel en el 404 que lanza al no encontrar la ruta que le pasas (porque oviamente no resuelve esa ruta al no estar corriendo node).

Adicionalmente, borra los archivos que pegaste ahi porque estan publicos y si tienes datos sensibles pues cualquiera los puede ver.

Comment: Si, el problema era como estaba montando el backend

Answer (score 0):

Hola también tuve un problema similar, al hacer deploy en `vercel` de un servidor `express` con `Apollo Server`, me aparecia el mismo error desde el cliente: "has been blocked by `CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource." en mi caso el `back` y el `front` estaban hechos con la infraestructura que brinda `apollo` para usar `GraphQl` y que el cliente estaba subido en otro host. en mi caso tuve que crear un archivo `vercel.json` y adicional a la configuracion estandar que sugiere `vercel`, ellos sugieren esto en la documentacion:[documentacion politica cors vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors#enabling-cors-using-vercel.json)
me lanzaba erro finalmente lo deje asi:

`vercel.json` file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "app.js",
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo importante de esta en el objeto de los `headers` en este caso lo muestro que cualquier origen pueda hacer peticiones, si tienes `url` especifica solo cambia el `"*"` por el enlace de tu dominio.

Importante: Recuerda que si estas usando `GraphQl`. Al final del enlace de tu dominio `backend` desde la petición en el cliente poner el `/Graphql` al final de lo contrario recibirás un `404`.

Nota: Hola, es mi primera respuesta, considero que podría ser útil por lo que en escancia es el mismo error pero con circunstancias y solución distinta espero les pueda ser útil he procurado no tener faltas ortográficas, si se me escapo alguna perdón.